# Convert multiple .txt files to .csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, csv

I have multiple .txt files and I want to convert them to .csv files with the same name. The filename for these .txt files is something like this:

```
01-09-2022-something.txt
02-09-2022-something.txt
03-09-2022-something.txt
04-09-2022-something.txt
.
.
.
.
31-09-2022-something.txt
```

I need to convert files like these to .csv but with the same name. Can anyone help me with this ?

Currently, I wrote this code to convert but for this, I have to know the file name and in my case filename is not static it is dynamic.

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = "/var/opt/something.txt"
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(file_path, delim_whitespace=True)
dataframe1.to_csv('something.csv', index = None)
```

Comment: Check out the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module in the standard library, in particular the [`with_suffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) method.

Comment: `file_path = file_path.replace('.txt', '.csv')`

Comment: use `for`-loop with `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob("*.txt")`

Comment: if you don't want to change data inside file then use `os.rename()`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
my_txt_files = [i for i in os.listdir('/var/opt') if i[-4:] == '.txt']
with open('/var/opt/something.csv', 'w') as out_f:
    for txt in my_txt_files:
        with open('/var/opt/' + txt, 'r') as in_f:
            out_f.write(in_f.read())
```

Comment: `['01-09-2022-something.txt', '02-09-2022-something.txt', '03-09-2022-something.txt'.........'31-09-2022-something.txt']` the output is coming like this any idea what to do after this?

Comment: Added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `for`-loop with `os.listdir()`  or `glob.glob("*.txt")`

And use `new_path = file_path.replace('.txt', '.csv')`

If you don't want to change data inside file then use `os.rename()`

```
import glob
import os

for file_path in glob.glob("/var/opt/*.txt")
    new_path = file_path.replace('.txt', '.csv')
    os.rename(file_path, new_path)
```

And if you want to make changes in data then use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

for file_path in glob.glob("/var/opt/*.txt")
    new_path = file_path.replace('.txt', '.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delim_whitespace=True)
    # ... some changes ...
    df.to_csv(new_path, index=None)
```